# How to determine windows build number using vb.net or c#?

Tags: vb.net

How to determine windows build number using vb.net or c#? I do not want to use win32 API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

System.OperatingSystem osInfo = System.Environment.OSVersion;

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304283

more detailed blog post : http://andrewensley.com/2009/06/c-detect-windows-os-part-1/

Comment: Unfortunately whilst the right answer at the time, it's broken on Windows 8.1 and 10 - see
 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn302074.aspx

Answer (score 3):

corsiKa got me on the right track, but it very much depends on what you need. I wanted the full build number, which changes with every Windows 10 Cumulative Update. (ex. 16299.192)

The WMI method is good, but only gets you 10.0.16299, which is the overall release. I used the WMI Code Creator to poke around, but couldn't find the "192" part in WMI.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\UBR
```

Has the 192 part of the build number.

I settled on this code to get 10.0.16299.192:

```
Function GetOSVersion() As String
    Dim strBuild1, strBuild2, strBuild3, strBuild4 As String
    Dim regKey As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
    regKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion")
    strBuild1 = regKey.GetValue("CurrentMajorVersionNumber")
    strBuild2 = regKey.GetValue("CurrentMinorVersionNumber")
    strBuild3 = regKey.GetValue("CurrentBuild")
    strBuild4 = regKey.GetValue("UBR")
    Return strBuild1 & "." & strBuild2 & "." & strBuild3 & "." & strBuild4
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

The `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion` registry key should contain it. I'm not sure if you can reference it without the win32 API, but you might be able to...

Answer (score 1):

You can get it through WMI. .Net 2.0

```
Imports System.Management

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Call GetOSVersion()
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetOSVersion()
        Dim sCaption As String = String.Empty
        Dim sVersion As String = String.Empty
        Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", _
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem")
        For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
            sCaption = DirectCast(queryObj("Caption"), String)
            sVersion = DirectCast(queryObj("Version"), String)
        Next
        Debug.WriteLine("OS: " & sCaption & " Ver " & sVersion)
    End Sub

End Class
```